# asp.net - Prevent multiple logins for a single user

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How can I prevent a single user from logging in to my asp.net website from more than one computer at the same time?

I have tried using the application server side state managenment but it is not work properly.

Comment: #1 consideration is to not screw up your site entirely. remember that the web itself is stateless and that a user can have a browser with 50 tabs open to your site. You don't want to break your site that it can't work in multiple tabs.

Comment: Several variations of this question have been asked.  Try browsing through http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=asp.net+prevent+multiple+logins for ideas.

Answer (score 1):

1) If you are Using Coookies to Track Users,

When a user logs in you write a unique guid to the database and store it in their authentication cookie, then every page request you check to see if they (GUIDs) are identical, and if not you log them off.

2) if not using cookies, Store the UserName, GUID in Application Cache, and user Session variable. Compare User Session to Aplpication Cache to see if he is already logged in.

Comment: but problem is that if user is closed browser wihout logout or power supplied is stop to that pc then without update that Guid to database and it will login forever......

Comment: The log would also likely contain an expiration timestamp.  If a match is found, update the timestamp with the current time.  If a user hasn't accessed the site for a set duration, clear out the GUID and require them to login again.

Comment: Ok, i guess i was not clear in my post :). When a User Logs in from a different browser, and if he is already logged in else where (GUID exists), you can create a new GUID for the User, and replace it in your Master Table. You need to decide if Last Login Kicks out prev user, or first login doesn't allow new user logins! does this help?

Comment: Yes, Jonathan is right. It is a very basic & important requirement to have some Expiration Policy!